# Generate a .DOT file from a RDF file

Tags: java, rdf, graphviz, dot, jena

I have an RDF file, from which I would like to generate a .dot file. I'd like to create a number of rules to style the nodes and the links between these nodes (such as a specific kind of arrow to represent a marriage relationship).

Here is an example of such a conversion "rule":

```
 <person rdf:about="http://www.something.com/EGAnne"
   <j: DateBirth>1981</j: DateBirth>
   <j:Profession>Comptable</j:Profession>
   <j:Gender>Female</j:Gender>
 </j:person>
```

I want to convert these lines to this result:

```
a [label = "Anne \ n \ nD.Birth: 1981 \ nProfession: Accounting \ n", shape = circle, fillcolor = "pink" style = "filled", fontsize = "9", fontname = " Arial, bold "];
```

Then, to represent the marriage between two instances of the class *person*, the type of arrow will be "odot" and color "goldenrod":

```
a -> j [arrowhead = "odot" arrowtail = "odot", dir = both, color = "goldenrod"]
```

How can I automatically generate the .dot file from RDF file, following rules like the one above?

Comment: I don't know of any RDF to DOT converter that supports this kind of behaviour, I suggest you find a working open source one and then adapt it to support styling rules in the way you have suggested

Answer (score 3):

This looks like it could work for you: [RDF-to-Dot](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2010/02/another-tiny-tool-rdf-to-dot.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. RDF-to-Dot tool does not allow to take into account specific "rules" as those I wrote above. :(

Answer (score 3):

xslt is my preferred way to create graphviz files from xml.

For you, the key part might look like this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="whateverThePathIs/person">
<xsl:if test="(./j:Gender &eq; 'Female')">
# Output a node for a Female
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="(./j:Gender &eq; 'Male')">
# Output a node for a Male
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be plenty up for the task: https://metacpan.org/pod/rdfdot

Answer (score 1):

the question is old (these were the days when people used to associate the color pink with the female gender :) but let me answer by promoting my pet [project](https://github.com/giacomociti/rdf2dot) because it provides exactly the kind of customization requested.

The following rules (save as .n3 and use as custom rules in the [playground](https://giacomociti.github.io/rdf2dot/)) cover the example:

```
@prefix log: <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/log#> .
@prefix string: <http://www.w3.org/2000/10/swap/string#> .
@prefix : <http://www.something.com/> .
@prefix attr: <http://view/dot/attribute/> .
@prefix v: <http://view/> .

{ 
    ?p a :Person ;
        log:localName ?name ;
        :DateBirth ?date ;
        :Profession ?profession .
    (?name '\n D.Birth: ' ?date '\n Profession: ' ?profession) string:concatenation ?label .
}
=>
{
    v:digraph v:hasNode ?p .
    ?p attr:label ?label ;
        attr:shape "circle" ;
        attr:style "filled" ;
        attr:fontsize "9" ;
        attr:fontname "Arial, bold" ;
} .

{ ?p :Gender "Female"} => { ?p attr:fillcolor "pink" } .
{ ?p :Gender "Male"} => { ?p attr:fillcolor "lightblue" } .


{  
    ?p1 :marriedTo ?p2 
} 
=> 
{ 
    v:digraph v:hasEdge [ 
        v:source ?p1 ; 
        v:target ?p2 ; 
        attr:arrowhead "odot" ; 
        attr:arrowtail "odot" ; 
        attr:dir "both" ; 
        attr:color "goldenrod" 
    ] 
} 
.
```

Applied to the RDF data (expressed in turtle because XML is less used these days):

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix : <http://www.something.com/> .

:Ann a :Person ;
   :DateBirth 1981 ;
   :Profession "Comptable" ;
   :Gender "Female" .

:Bob a :Person ;
   :DateBirth 1981 ;
   :Profession "Comptable" ;
   :Gender "Male" .

:Ann :marriedTo :Bob .
```

produce the requested diagram:

[image: ann and bob]